# How to get the time duration from two date-time columns of pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have two date-time columns in my pandas data frame; How can I find the difference in hours (numeric)?

- For example the duration from
  2018-07-30 19:03:04 to 2018-07-31 11:00:48
  is 15.962 hours.
  When I subtract two columns, I get 15:57:43.430000, which is not desired.

Comment: Please post reproducible code/data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take seconds from [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) then divide it with `60*60`.
Dividing because `60 Seconds -> 1 Minute` and `60 Minutes -> 1 Hour` so the output will be in the number of hours.

Code:

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime('2018-07-30 19:03:04')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('2018-07-31 11:00:48')
(t2-t1).seconds/(60*60)
15.962222222222222
```

When you subtract them you will get default view of timedelta representation where first it shows days then hours followed by minutes,seconds and microseconds. That is the you are getting `15:57:44` value.

```
t2-t1
Timedelta('0 days 15:57:44')
```

The value of `15:57:44` is rounded because the t1 and t2 does not have microseconds in the question.

To use this concept on `series` you need to use `apply` method like below.
The `DateTime` columns are generated and shuffled.

**Code:**

```
dates = pd.date_range('2018-08-23 02:34:54','2018-08-24 00:00:00',periods=22).values
np.random.shuffle(dates)
df = pd.DataFrame(dates.reshape(11,2),columns=['t1','t2'])
df
                               t1                              t2
0   2018-08-23 21:57:36.571428608   2018-08-23 08:42:04.285714176
1   2018-08-23 07:40:52.571428608   2018-08-23 22:58:48.285714176
2   2018-08-23 16:51:38.000000000   2018-08-23 11:45:39.428571392
3   2018-08-24 00:00:00.000000000   2018-08-23 04:37:17.428571392
4   2018-08-23 10:44:27.714285824   2018-08-23 12:46:51.142857216
5   2018-08-23 06:39:40.857142784   2018-08-23 13:48:02.857142784
6   2018-08-23 15:50:26.285714176   2018-08-23 03:36:05.714285824
7   2018-08-23 02:34:54.000000000   2018-08-23 09:43:16.000000000
8   2018-08-23 05:38:29.142857216   2018-08-23 18:54:01.428571392
9   2018-08-23 14:49:14.571428608   2018-08-23 19:55:13.142857216
10  2018-08-23 20:56:24.857142784   2018-08-23 17:52:49.714285824
```

---

```
(df['t1']-df['t2']).apply(lambda x: x.seconds/(60*60))
0     13.258889
1      8.701111
2      5.099444
3     19.378333
4     21.960000
5     16.860556
6     12.238889
7     16.860556
8     10.740833
9     18.900278
10     3.059722
dtype: float64
```

**Update:**
Faster approach than above:

```
(df['t1']-df['t2'])/np.timedelta64(1,'h')
```

Comment: Thank you but it gives this error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds' when I apply it on my dataframe column.

Comment: @P.J please check the updated solution to apply on series. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Worked. I appreciate your help.